# updating a dictionary with names for array columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary with some NumPy array columns and their names. What is a pythonic way to do it?
The code below does not give me the correct result.
The dict `d` should have the variable name as a key and the appropriate column as value.
for example {'X': first column,...}

```
names = ['X' , 'Y', 'Z', 'W']
d = {}
x = np.random.randint(100, size = 40).reshape(10,4) 
for i in range(0,len(names)):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        d[names[i]] = x[:,j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
d = dict(zip(names,x.T))
```

`x.T` transposes the array, so it's of shape (4,10) instead of (10,4).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a `for` loop you could use:

```
d = {}
for n , c in zip(names, range(x.shape[1])):
    d[n] = x[:,c]
```

or:

```
d = {}
for n , c in zip(names, x.T):
    d[n] = c
```

if you want a dictionary comprehension (a bit faster):

```
{n: x[:,c]  for n , c in zip(names, range(x.shape[1]))}
```

or

```
{k: v for k, v in zip(names, x.T)}
```

output:

```
{'X': array([18, 51,  1, 41, 57, 66,  7, 30, 40, 83]),
 'Y': array([87,  2,  6, 64, 25, 80, 47, 81, 50, 84]),
 'Z': array([50, 48, 13, 94, 40, 21, 71, 31, 23, 49]),
 'W': array([32, 49, 95, 58, 87, 83, 10, 50, 83, 85])}
```